# What is the difference between electron-builder and electron-rebuild?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder, electron-rebuild

I am trying to find out the difference between [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) and [electron-rebuild](https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild) for compiling native modules. Afaik there are these two options to compile my native module dependencies:

**electron-builder**

> "Native application dependencies compilation (including Yarn support)."

```
    % npm i
    % npm run electron-builder install-app-deps
```

And there is
**electron-rebuild**

> This allows you to use native Node.js modules **in Electron apps without your system version of Node.js matching exactly** (which is often not the case, and sometimes not even possible).

```
% npm run electron-rebuild
```

Both result in a working binary of my dependency. I know `electron-builder` is used for more, but why does `electron-rebuild` exist if this can be done via `electron-builder` as well? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There's also `npm rebuild`.

The reason that both exist is like the reason that both Windows and Mac exist - but they also both exist for another reason.

Electron-Builder provides a complete solution to build and package your app, and Electron-Rebuild is just for rebuilding dependencies. If you're not using Electron-Builder to package your app, then having it just for its rebuild capabilities seems excessive.

Mostly though, Electron-Rebuild was used back in the day when Electron and Node ABIs didn't match up which made problems for `npm rebuild` to rebuild node dependencies for Electron - hence the need for a special solution.

I'm no expert on the history and there may be other reasons `electron-rebuild` exists, but I can't see any use for it today unless you're on old versions of Electron.

**Edit:** It looks like `electron-rebuild` may still have some benefits [based on this PR](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/pull/7196)